# How to allow only specific directories to use htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, directory, ubuntu-9.04

Currently in apache2.conf I have `AllowOverride all` set for `/var/www` which simply allows htaccess for all the sites on the server (which is Ubuntu, 9.04).

However, I'd rather only allow overrides in each site root directory and nothing else. In other words, `/var/www/site1`, `/var/www/site2`, etc. can have a htaccess, but all other directories including `/var/www` and `/var/www/site1/content` cannot.

Is there a way to do this without having to write a rule for every site on the server?

EDIT: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough. But I have just tried a couple of things that didn't work as expected. I set `AllowOverride none` for the root directory then `all` for specific directories like this:

```
<Directory ~ "^/var/www/site1$">
  AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

However, when loading a URL like `site1.com/section/page` the page cannot not be found (shows the browser error page, not my 404 page). Note `section/page` is not a real filesystem URL, it's a rewrite.

It was my understanding that:

1. In the previous configuration, Apache would look for a htaccess in `/var/www/site1/section` (which doesn't exist), then try `/var/www/site1`, and then any parent directories.
2. With the directives above, Apache should now just look at `/var/www/site1` and no other directories. But that doesn't seem to be working...

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an arbitrary amount of Directory tags and configure them independently.

You can do this by VirtualHost too.

Like:

```
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem though. I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can set that by Virtual Hosts, if you are using Virtual Hosts.

HTH,

KM

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old but if anyone else comes across this, you can use the standard "*" wildcard character in paths, which matches any character except a slash, so the following would restrict htaccess to only your site root directories and no subdirectories:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/site*>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/site*/*>
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```